# Reporting Services XML Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

Really annoying issue that I have spent a long time on. I shall switch into Software Testing Bug Report mode (from a past life) to explain it.

**Scenario**

- I have modified a SSRS report to work with a new database structure
- The report uses a stored procedure which takes 4 parameters
- One of these parameters has been added to work with the new database structure
- Stored procedure works perfectly in SQL management studio
- Query works perfectly in the query designer window of report builder

**Expected Results**

- I expect that the dataset will show the fields when expanded
- I expect that the report will run correctly

**Actual Results**

- No fields appear under the dataset in the Report Data Pane of report builder
- Report does not run
- I get the following error:

> There is an unclosed literal string. Line 1, position 64737.
>   ----------------------------  Response is not well-formed XML.
>   ----------------------------  The attempt to connect to the report server failed.  Check your connection information and that the report
>   server is a compatible version.

**Notes**

I have tried everything I can think of, including searching the report definition for unclosed strings but no banana.

Has anyone else come up with this error in SSRS Report Builder?

**Technologies Used**

- SQL Server 2008 R2
- SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2
- Report Builder 3.0
- Building report on my local machine running Windows 7
- Running report on SQL Server Remote Machine running Windows Server 2008

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is not too late.  But to anyone who comes across this same question I had a similar issue and I resolved it by removing my tablix that was generated and was still referencing fields no longer available in my updated sproc.

All I did was to delete said tablix and regenerate it using the wizard and my issue was resolved.  I would propose that you recreate whatever you are using to display the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

If you cant find any malformed XML in your report definition I would check the data the stored procedure is pulling. If there is a <, >, or any other symbol that would break XML in the actual data this could cause you to get this error. Try pulling the report with a parameter that would cause no data to come back and see if you still get this error. If not then the problem could be in the data that comes back.